# Explanation of Jaynes' Probability theory formula 4.70

Tags: probability, probability-theory, taylor-expansion, self-learning

I have read this derivation.
**$$L(f)\equiv{lng(f|DX)}=nln(f)+(N-n)ln(1-f)+const \;(4.69) $$
expand L(f) in a power series about $\hat{f}$.The first terms as
$$L(f) = L(\hat{f}) - \frac{(f-\hat{f})^2}{2\sigma^2}+... \;(4.70)$$ , where $$\sigma^2 \equiv\frac{\hat{f}(1-\hat{f})}{N},\; where \;n = Nf$$**

**But I can not get that result like 4.70.**
For $$L'(\hat{f})=\frac{(n-n\hat{f} - N\hat{f}+n\hat{f})}{\hat{f}(1-\hat{f})}=\frac{N(f-\hat{f})}{\hat{f}(1-\hat{f})}$$,
So I will give my result with $$L(f)=L(\hat{f})+\frac{(f-\hat{f})^2}{\frac{\hat{f}(1-\hat{f})}{N}}+...\;(4.71)$$
**I don't think (4.71) is the same as 4.70.** So i posted this thread.
Where am i wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, as explained in (4.68), $$\hat f=\frac{n}N$$ and one knows that, for every $f$ in $(0,1)$, $$L'(f)=\frac{n}f-\frac{N-n}{1-f}$$ hence $$L'(\hat f)=0$$ Thus, one expects that, for $f$ close to $\hat f$, $$L(f)-L(\hat f)\sim\frac12L''(\hat f)(f-\hat f)^2$$ hence the relevant quantity is $$L''(\hat f)$$ Compute it, and the fog you put yourself in should dissolve by itself...

Comment: A general remark about your posts here: Please stop mentioning "errors" or "contradictions" or what-have-you in Jaynes' treatise when, more plausibly and more often than not, the trouble lies in your misunderstanding of the text.